# Loop through a specific parent category

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I have a list of regions (NA, EUW, etc) set as subcategories, and the parent is `regions`. I need to list through these regions for my post types.

```
<?php
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'packages',
    'category_name' => 'NA',
    'meta_key' => 'package_order_id',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC'
));

if ($posts)
    {
    foreach($posts as $post)
        {
        setup_postdata($post);
?>
```

..

Where `category_name' => 'NA'`, would instead be `category_name' => <?php regions[i] ?>,`. This would be within the category loop.

My attempt found within another answer only looped through all of the categories.

```
<?php 
$categories = get_categories(
    array( 'regions' => $cat->cat_ID )
);

foreach ($categories as $c) {
    var_dump($c);
}

?>
```

But I only need it to loop in the `regions` parent category for child category names. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the ID of the `regions` category and then use `get_categories()` to get all categories that have that ID as their parent:

```
$parent = get_category_by_slug( 'regions' );

$regions = get_categories( array(
    'parent' => $parent->term_id,
) );

foreach ( $regions as $region ) {
    // Do stuff.
}
```

Have you considered just creating a "Regions" custom taxonomy for your post type though? It's a little unusual having categories work like this. It's fragile too since it depends on a category having a specific name.

If you did that, and set the taxonomy name as `region`, you'd loop through them like so:

```
$regions = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'region' ) );

foreach ( $regions as $region ) {
    // Do stuff.
}
```

Comment: Can you manage taxonomies from wp-admin?

Comment: Yes, they look and behave the same way as categories, but stored separately. Same idea as custom post types but for categories/tags.

Comment: Alright once I added the regions via taxonomies, what would the code look like to loop through that?

Comment: Updated my answer